# Compare two polars DataFrames for equality

Tags: python, python-polars

How do I compare two polars `DataFrames` for value equality? It appears that `==` is only true if the two tables are the same object:

```py
import polars as pl
pl.DataFrame({"x": [1,2,3]}) == pl.DataFrame({"x": [1,2,3]})  # False
```

Comment: Appears this has changed in later versions of polars. In `polars==0.19.12` the example doesn't return a single booleean but instead a mask of `bool` where the value is true if they match and false if not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the `equals` method of `DataFrame`:

```py
import polars as pl
pl.DataFrame({"x": [1,2,3]}).frame_equal(pl.DataFrame({"x": [1,2,3]}))  # True
```

Before version 0.19.16, it was called `frame_equals`.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the correct answer above, it is good to note that for unit testing there is [polars.testing.assert_frame_equal](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.testing.assert_frame_equal.html#polars.testing.assert_frame_equal), which provides better error reporting, has more configuration options and raises an assertion on False.

Answer (score 7):

## *Update.* November 2023

As of [polars 0.19.16](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/releases/tag/py-0.19.16), `frame_equals` was deprecated in favour of  [`pl.DataFrame.equals`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.equals.html#polars.DataFrame.equals).

```py
import polars as pl

pl.DataFrame({"x": [1,2,3]}).equals(pl.DataFrame({"x": [1,2,3]})) # True
```